# Why b doesn't change always its value when I run ((a++)) && ((b++)) in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line

Let's take the following example from my terminal:

```bsh
$ a=0 && b=1
$ echo $a $b
0 1
$ # Everything OK
$ ((a++)) && ((b++))
$ echo $a $b
1 1
$ # What? Why only a changed its value and b no?
$ ((a++)) && ((b++))
$ echo $a $b
2 2
$ # Now the value of b has changed...
```

Can someone to make me understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`((a++))` increments the value of `$a` in `1`. Its exit status `$?` is 0 if the evaluated expression was not `0` and `1` otherwise. If its exit status is, than, because of `&&` the second command - `((b++))` - will not run.

As `man bash` indicates, *if the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1*. As per `a++` being a post-increment expression, the expression evaluates `$a` itself and then increments its value, so that the return status of `((a++))` will be `0` when the expression is non-zero, and `1` otherwise.

So, counter-intuitively:

- when `$a` is unset, the return status will be `1`.
- when `$a` is a string, the return status will be `1`.
- when `$a` is equal to `0`, the return status will be `1`.
- when `$a` is set to a number different from 0, the return status will be `0`.

#### See an example:

The variable is `0`.

```
$ t=0
```

We perform `((t++))` and see what the command is returning with the `echo $( command )` expression:

```
$ echo $(((t++)))
0
```

But note that the value of `$t` has been incremented.

```
$ echo $t
1
```

The same if we do it again:

```
$ echo $(((t++)))
1
$ echo $t
2

$ echo $(((t++)))
2
$ echo $t
3
```

---

See `man bash`:

> **((expression))**
>
> The expression is evaluated according to the rules described below
>   under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  **If the value of the expression is
>   non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1**. 
>   This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".

Comment: If *`((a++))` returns the value of `$a`* which is 0, than the command was a success. But no, `echo $?` prints `1` which is contradictory with what you said...

Comment: I don't see a contradiction. As we all see the command was successful (value is incremented) what I don't know is why `$?` returns 1.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu see updated answer referring to `man bash`: "If the value of the expression is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise the return status is 1".

Comment: It wasn't me. I just give you a + for `man bash` which explain somehow what I didn't undertood... But you must to change *((a++)) returns the value of $a* from your answer, because it's clear that is not like this.

Comment: If you can explain clear why *((a++)) has a return status of 1*, maybe I can accept your answer.

Comment: I guess it is a problem on the words we are using. `echo 234` has an exit status of 0 and returns 234. Will try to rephrase in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`a++` is *post*-increment, i.e. the increment happens *after* the value is tested.

The test on `a` fails because `a` is zero at the time it is tested.

Comment: Good one! If you do `((++c)) && echo "yes"` it returns `yes` even if `$c` is not set, while `((c++)) && echo "yes"` does not.

Comment: One moment... The test?!? What test? AFAIK, in bash `[[ ... ]]` is used for test, while `(( ... ))` evaluate an arithmetic expression...

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: `&&` runs the second operand only if the first one is true. That's called "short-circuiting".

Comment: @choroba Ok, this part is very clear for me, but how can be `((a++))` true or false? Is this an error?

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: Every command has an exit status. You can use `if (( c == d + e ))` as well as `if (( x ))`, similarly to C.

Comment: @choroba But there is no any `if`, `[[ ... ]]` or `test` in my command. I just use a bash arithmetic expression to increment a number... For me this should return true if the operation was successful and false if not... like `((a=a/0))` which obviously will never be successful.

Comment: @choroba Take a look also to `let a++ && let b++` . It behave exactly the same... But where is the ***test***.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu: There is no test. Commands return an exit status. Arithmetical operations return 1 for zero, so you can write `if (( c ))`.

Comment: Now I get it. But you and Stuart have expressed as if there is a test.

Answer (score 3):

&& is the logical AND operator. If its first argument is false, it doesn't bother evaluating the second. This is called "short-circuiting" and saves processing time.

Since ++ is post increment, if a is zero when evaluating `((a++)) && ((b++))`, it evaluates a first, gets zero (which is false), adds 1 to a, then quits due to the short-circuit without evaluating the second part. So b does not get incremented.

Answer (score 1):

When `a` is 0, the value of `((a++))` is interpreted as not true.